# Premarital Sex Before Becoming Muslim

Tags: conversion, forgiveness

As Salam Alaikum

I am a convert to Islam and prior to becoming a Muslim I was an atheist. When I was younger I had sex with an ex girlfriend prior to either of us being married. I was reading Surah an-Nur and it states two things of importance to me

1. People who commit fornication must be flogged 100 times for their actions
2. Men who have commited fornication must marry women who have done the same

Do these rulings apply to me even though I was not Muslim?

Alhamdulilah

Comment: Accepting Islam erases all previous sins.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Here some relevant posts: [Morality of forgiveness in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49988/morality-of-forgiveness-in-islam), [Are certain sins forgiven after conversion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/are-certain-sins-forgiven-after-conversion-to-islam-sunni-view) and to some extent [Do my good deeds committed before conversion to Islam count?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36231/do-my-good-deeds-committed-before-converting-to-islam-count)

Answer (score -2):

As salam alaykom,

Of course not. converting to Islam makes you as white as snow.